# INSERT INTO, Multiple WHERE IN, Check if value exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am collecting information about 30 posts with title and content in a multidimensional array which is relatively long and then put all of them into database by one MySQL query. But my checking query is separate from that inserting. I am checking similar post by the new post's title and then insert it. How can I merge the checking query with the inserting one?

This is my multidimensional array about 30 posts :

```
    array(
        [0] => array(
            [post_title] => $postTitle1,
            [post_content] => $contentTitle1,
        )
        [1] => array(
            [post_title] => $postTitle2,
            [post_content] => $contentTitle2,
        )
        [N] => array(
            [post_title] => $postTitleN,
            [post_content] => $contentTitleN,
        )
    );
```

---

This is my checking query by the new post's title (is done for each post and works fine):

```
SELECT post_title FROM x_post WHERE post_title=$newPostTitle
```

---

This is my inserting query (works fine):

```
INSERT INTO x_post (`post_title`, `post_content`, `date_created`, `user_id`)
                              VALUES ((((( My multidimensional array's information will be here after processing )))))
```

---

---

and Finally this is the query what I want to have but it does not work (to merge two queries):

```
INSERT INTO x_post (`post_title`, `post_content`, `date_created`, `user_id`) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT  $postTitle1, $content1,  $time, $userId") AS tmp1, (SELECT  $postTitle2, $content2,  $time, $userId") AS tmp2, .......... and so on ........... , (SELECT  $postTitle30, $content30,  $time, $userId") AS tmp30 WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT x_post.post_title FROM x_post WHERE x_post.post_title IN ($newPostTitle1, $newPostTitle2, ... and so on... , $newPostTitleN))
```

What is the best way to write the query ?
In fact I want to check all the 30 posts if similar is exist in one query and then insert those has not similar.
I know it is complicated, but would be a great query.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you explain what the purpose of the checking query is?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - I want to check if the title is exist, Inserting be not performed for that post.

Comment: Isn't the title a very poor choice for this? What if two 'posts' have the same title, but a completely different content? I am sorry for these questions, but you've given us so little insight in what you're actually working with. Normally you would use some unique feature of a record for this, like an unique id.

Comment: Yes, Maybe it seems a poor choice. But the system which I am using, will not have same titles. But I am agree with you for normal systems.

Comment: Well, OK, anyway, I believe the best system is what you have been using: Check the titles with one query, remove duplicates from your `$array` and then insert the remaining posts with the other query. Anything else will get quite unreadable/unmanageble. Checking 30 posts is not a disaster, and even if you had a single query, it would still have to do the same job. You could also check the 30 posts with one query, by using `OR` in the `WHERE` part of the query, and then delete all found titles from the `$array`. That leaves you with only 2 queries to run.

Comment: I am doing right now as you said and run checking query for every post. But I want do all in one query to speed up the query. Speed is the same in both situations?

Comment: Well, 30 separate checks will be slightly slower that 1 big check, but combining these checks and the insert query, in one big query, will not speed things up. But test this, so you know for your self.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` to make a set of your individual `FROM`-less `SELECT`s which you can then use as just one derived table instead of 30. And instead of using `IN` in the `WHERE` clause you can just correlate directly.

```
INSERT INTO x_post
            (`post_title`,
             `post_content`,
             `date_created`,
             `user_id`) 
            SELECT `post_title`,
                   `post_content`,
                   `date_created`,
                   `user_id`
                   FROM (SELECT $postTitle1 `post_title`,
                                $content1 `post_content`,
                                $time `date_created`,
                                $userId `user_id`
                         UNION ALL
                         ...
                         UNION ALL
                         SELECT $postTitle30 `post_title`,
                                $content30 `post_content`,
                                $time `date_created`,
                                $userId `user_id`) tmp
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                            FROM x_news
                                            WHERE x_news.news_title = tmp.`post_title`);
```

Comment: Hello @sticky-bit, I did some edits to my final query, 'news' replaced by 'post'. Does it matter?

Comment: @AmirhosseinTarmast: Hmm, MySQL can have problems, when a `SELECT` is done in a statement on a table that is changed by the statement. But you can try. Just rename the thing s my query accordingly and see what you get.

Comment: I got this error : failed due to Table 'mydatabase.tmp' doesn't exist.
I Also used "as tmp" in the query, but got same error again.